# Does a linear regression assume that the (unconditional) predictor data is i.i.d?

Tags: regression, least-squares, estimators, consistency

Say I have a linear, cross sectional relationship -

$y_{i}=x_{i}b+e_{i}$.

Where $E(e_{i}|X_{j})=0$ for all relevant $i,j$. Given this, one can prove that the OLS estimator is unbiased.

However, consistency requires us to use the law of large numbers on the samples $x_{i}$ - because we assume that $E(xx')$ is proxied well by its sample counterpart:

[image: Wikipedia proof of consistency]

Clearly this only follows if we assume that the predictor data is i.i.d. Am I correct in assuming this?

Comment: It's hard to see in what sense you could make *any* statement about what happens asymptotically unless you make a specific assumption about the sequence of $x_i.$  Although *iid* is not the only possibility, the assumption must be *something* specific (such as second-order stationary).